# Jmeter Complex Parametrized Calls

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to simulate a flow between two webpages.

The case is complex since the call to the second webpage is done through a form passing a list of input parameters generated by a javascript function called when the user click on the button to pass to the second webpage

If i open firebug console I can see into POST the list of parameters i'm interested in

1. Due to the fact that i need to parametrize the Jmeter POST with the list of generated parameters is there any solution?
2. If it's not suitable any solution i'm considering to use regex to extract from the webpage the parameters the javascript function works with. However i really cannot find the parameter value since it is stored into a javascript variable: if i look at the html source code i see something like:

   ```
   this.cabinNumber[numeroCabina]=$(&apos;#cabinnumber&apos;+numeroCabina).val();&#xd;
   ```

   but i do not see the real value; (cabinNumberis te variable i'm interested in)
3. Is there any chance to read directly from HTTP Response Parameters maybe using BeanShell?

Please note that the webpage is developed with Struts1 technology

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser and it cannot execute JavaScript on client pages, but:

1. If JavaScript doesn't assume communication with the server (which is unlikely) you should be able to replicate function using any suitable JMeter scripting extension starting with [__javaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function, [Beanshell Scripting](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) or even custom implementation of Java Sampler. Or alternatively "interesting" value is already in the response, it just hidden via styles
2. If it does (which is more common case) you can catch the request via firebug and replicate it with JMeter to retrieve desired cabin number.

You can also try comparing requests captured with firebug to requests captured by [JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) and investigate the differences if any.

Comment: in solution 1: can javascript/java read from http response parameters?. Please assume my servlet stored the parameter "cabin" into the response message

Comment: What do you call "http response parameters"? You can get response code, Headers, message and data. Depending on where your `cabin` resides approaches may differ.

Comment: The paramers are setted into URL

Comment: I'm trying to use beanshell to get URL:  `import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils; 
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult; String currentURL= SampleResult.getUrlAsString();
log.info(currentURL);` but i get errors

Comment: For Beanshell Pre Processor `log.info(sampler.getUrl().getQuery());`, for Beanshell Post Processor: `log.info(prev.getURL().getQuery());`. In your case SampleResult is not defined so error is expected.